# Psycopg2 insert list of nested dictionaries into multiple tables

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, nested, psycopg2

So i have list of nested dictionaries which from i want to get values and insert them into tables on my Postgresql 14 database. I'm using Python with Psycopg2.

List looks like this...

**List of nested dictionaries**

```
[
 {
  "trainNumber": 1,
  "departureDate": "2020-12-08",
  "cancelled": false,
  "trainType": "IC",
  "0": {
   "type": "DEPARTURE",
   "stationShortCode": "HKI",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-12-08T04:57:00.000Z"
  },
  "1": {
   "type": "ARRIVAL",
   "stationShortCode": "PSL",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-12-08T05:02:00.000Z"
  },
  "2": {
   "type": "DEPARTURE",
   "stationShortCode": "PSL",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-12-08T05:03:00.000Z"
  },
{
  "trainNumber": 2,
  "departureDate": "2020-12-08",
  "cancelled": false,
  "trainType": "S",
  "0": {
   "type": "DEPARTURE",
   "stationShortCode": "JNS",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-12-08T03:12:00.000Z"
  },
  "1": {
   "type": "ARRIVAL",
   "stationShortCode": "PLT",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-12-08T03:12:34.000Z"
  },
  "2": {
   "type": "DEPARTURE",
   "stationShortCode": "PLT",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-12-08T03:12:34.000Z"
  },
```

**Query for Psycopg2**

```
insert_query = WITH test AS (
    INSERT INTO trains_data.trains (train_number, train_type)
    VALUES (%(trainNumber)s, %(trainType)s)
    RETURNING id
), test2 as (
    INSERT INTO trains_data.train_routes (train_id, date)
    VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM test), %(departureDate)s)
    RETURNING id
), test3 as (
    INSERT INTO trains_data.train_timetables (route_id, scheduled_time, station_id, route_type, cancelled)
    VALUES ( (SELECT id FROM test2), %(scheduledTime)s, (SELECT station_id FROM trains_data.train_stations WHERE short_name = %(stationShortCode)s), %(type)s, %(cancelled)s)
);
```

Problem is that when i run this query i get `KeyError: 'scheduledTime'`
So my questions are:

1. How can i access nested dictionaries where i need to get time, type and stationShortCode values or is it even possible?
2. Should i consider some different kinda approach to insert my data?
3. Is my SQL code somewhat correct to insert data correctly?

Any kinda help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue is the `train_timetables` data are a series of dictionaries keyed to `0, 1, 2` with the nested dictionaries containing the keys you are using as the placeholders in the query. At some point you will need to iterate over them an pull that data out. One way would be in the Python code before you create the insert queries. Another possibility would be to push the data in as JSON and then use the [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)  to expand the data an insert from that. The second suggestion is speculative at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking to pull the data out into new dictionary but then i should create second query where i insert all the `stationShortCode, type and scheduledTime` data and somehow connect them into correct `trainNumber` in my database and i cant figure out how i can achieve that. @AdrianKlaver